# Ruby 3 RBS type checking

Tags: ruby, rbs

Don't understand how to write and setup ruby 3 RBS type checking.

Let's say I have a similar file:

```
### file name: my_project/book.rb
class Book
  def initialize(pages)
    @pages = pages
  end
  
  def pages
    @pages
  end
end

first_book = Book.new(100)
puts first_book.pages
```

The question: What should a `.rbs` file look like to my file example?
And what CLI command should I run to test it ?
For example `$rbs my_project *` or something like this ?

Comment: It would help if you could explain what, precisely is unclear to you about the documentation of RBS. That way, you avoid us repeating things you already know, or repeating things you already read und didn't understand. Also, it would help the Ruby developers improve the documentation if you could tell them what's wrong with it. That way, future developers don't stumble over the same problems you did. Make the world a better place!

Comment: @JörgWMittag First is _how to setup type checking of all files inside some project from terminal.  Second is _RBS files location structure_.  
And If you can write some little any example RBS for code, which I wrote - it will help me navigate the documentation more easily

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Don't understand how to write and setup ruby 3 RBS type checking.

You are confusing three completely different things here:

1. A *Type Language*
2. A *Type System*
3. A *Type Checker*

RBS is #1, a *Type Language*. It is exactly what it sounds like: a *Language* for writing down *Types*.

It says *nothing* about what those types *mean* (that would be a *Type System*), and it says nothing about whether or not a program is *well-typed* with respect to a type system (that would be a *Type Checker*).

RBS was developed based on the observation that there are multiple type checkers in the community already. E.g. almost every Ruby IDE contains a type checker to be able to provide better code completion and "red squigglies". There is Sorbet. There is Steep. There are a couple of others.

There are multiple incompatible type languages already in the Ruby community. The Ruby core library and standard library RDoc comments sometimes use an informal one. YARD has type annotations, but no type language. (They only give an example of what a type language *could* look like.) Some people write YARD type annotation using the example type language, so use a homegrown or modified one. Then there is RBI, used by Sorbet.

The idea behind RBS is to provide *one* Type Language as part of the Ruby Language with one API for querying that language. This will allow on the one hand interoperability between existing type checkers and on the other hand more competition. (At the moment, there is a lock-in effect: every type checker uses a different type language, so you can't easily exchange them without rewriting your type signatures from scratch in a different type language. If they use a common type language, you can easily swap them out and choose the best one for your use case.)

The second half of the RBS project is to ship a complete set of RBS signatures for the whole Ruby core library and standard library. That is another problem with the current state of affairs: every type checker has to do this over and over and over again, they all have to write type signatures for the Ruby core and standard libraries in their own type language from scratch. With RBS, there is going to be one standard set of type signatures for the Ruby core and standard libraries.

Also, writing signatures for projects like Rails becomes much easier because you only have to write *one* set of signatures and you know that it will work with *every* type checker, every IDE, every linter, every static analyzer, etc.

> The question: What should a `.rbs` file look like to my file example?

That depends: what is it that you want to say?

```rbs
class Book[T]
  @pages: T
  def initialize: (pages: T) -> void
  def pages: () -> T
end
```

Is one possible type definition.

```rbs
class Book[T]
  attr_reader pages: T
  def initialize: (pages: T) -> void
end
```

might be a slightly better one that captures your *intent* better than the first one. (Since I don't know your intent but can only see your code, I can't tell which is better.)

```rbs
class Book
  attr_reader pages: 100
  def initialize: (pages: 100) -> void
end
```

Is another possible type definition. This is the strictest possible type signature that will still allow your sample code to run.

```rbs
class Book
  attr_reader pages: Numeric
  def initialize: (pages: Numeric) -> void
end
```

Is also possible, as is

```rbs
class Book
  attr_reader pages: Integer
  def initialize: (pages: Integer) -> void
end
```

And of course, this is also *always* valid, albeit useless since it doesn't tell us anything that we don't already know:

```rbs
class Book
  attr_reader pages: untyped
  def initialize: (pages: untyped) -> untyped
end
```

Technically speaking, both of the methods in your code take an optional block, whereas we have disallowed that here. To match the semantics of your code *exactly*, the signature should probably be this:

```rbs
class Book[T]
  @pages: T
  def initialize: (pages: T) ?{ (*args: void) -> void } -> void
  def pages: () ?{ (*args: void) -> void } -> T
end
```

This last one is the one that most closely matches what your code currently does and allows. Whether this also accurately captures what you *want* your code to do and allow, that is a completely different question which only you can answer.

> And what CLI command should I run to test it ?

It is not quite clear what mean by "test it". If you mean "type check it", then as I said before: RBS is *not* a type checker, it is simply a language for *writing* types, it doesn't know and doesn't care what you *do* with those types.

RBS *does* have a test mode, however, but that does something different: it can look at your *running* code and see whether your code violates any of the type constraints *at runtime*. However, this is *not* static type checking.

For example, if you have this signature:

```rbs
class Foo
  def bar:  () -> Integer
  def quux: () -> Integer
end
```

and this code:

```ruby
class Foo
  def bar;  23           end
  def quux; 'fourty-two' end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.bar
```

It will *not* complain, because it never observed `Foo#quux` violating the type constraint at runtime.

And if you have this definition of `Foo#quux` instead:

```ruby
def quux; if rand < 0.5 then 42 else 'fourty-two' end end
```

Then it will sometimes complain and sometimes not, provided that you actually call `quux` somewhere.

So, whether or not you catch any problems depends on your test coverage. If you have a method that returns the wrong type when called with a particular combination of arguments, but you never call it with this particular combination of arguments in your tests, then you will never notice.

Note that this is *not* so much testing the correctness of your *code*, it is more for testing the correctness of your *type signatures*.

> For example `$rbs my_project *` or something like this ?

The tools that ship with RBS are *primarily* designed as libraries, because it is expected that they are going to be integrated in documentation tools (to show type signatures in documentation), test harnesses (to test your type signatures), IDEs (for code completion), or in *type checkers*.

For example, the testing tool I mentioned above is intended to be used like this:

```ruby
RBS_TEST_TARGET='Foo::*' bundle exec ruby -r rbs/test/setup test/foo_test.rb
```

What `rbs/test/setup` will do, is very stupidly just ask for `Foo.constants.grep(Module)`, then for each of those modules do `mod.instance_methods(false)` and literally replace each method with a wrapper that checks the types at method entry and exit and calls the original method. (Using the same technique that ActiveSupport's `alias_method_chain` uses.)

As you can see, this is not very command line friendly, it is intended to be integrated into the test harness as a library.

There *are* a couple of command line tools available:

- `rbs ast` prints out an AST of the current environment in JSON format
- `rbs list` prints out a list of the types in the current environment
- `rbs ancestors` prints out the ancestors of a module
- `rbs methods` prints out the methods of a module
- `rbs method` prints out a method
- `rbs validate` validates the syntax of RBS files and does some basic semantic sanity checks
- `rbs constant` performs constant lookup
- `rbs paths` prints out the paths where RBS looks for signature files
- `rbs prototype` can generate a skeleton type signature to get you started, it can do this either from your code or from an already existing RBI type signature. (RBI is the type language used by the Sorbet type checker.)
- `rbs vendor` vendors signature files into the project directory
- `rbs parse` parses an RBS file and prints syntax errors
- `rbs test` runs your tests with the above-mentioned test hooks injected

However, note that this CLI is *not* intended as the primary interface to RBS. The [README](https://github.com/ruby/rbs#cli) explicitly says:

> The gem ships with the `rbs` command line tool to demonstrate what it can do and help develop RBS.

The CLI is meant as an *example* for how to use the API, not as the primary entry point into the API.

Comment: Much answer, much wow! Thank you! Especially the part about the testing tool was exactly what I searched for.

Answer (score 6):

I try to make a simple example using ruby 3.0.0 to test the Static Analysis with rbs syntax.

#### 1. Ruby file

```rb
# book.rb
class Book
  def initialize(pages)
    @pages = pages
  end

  def pages
    @pages
  end
end

first_book = Book.new(100)
puts first_book.pages
```

#### 2. Generate rbs file

```
typeprof book.rb > book.rbs
```

#### 3. Use [steep](https://github.com/soutaro/steep) CLI as a type checker.

first, we need this configuration file:

```
# Steepfile
target :lib do
  signature "."
  check "book.rb"
end
```

And run:

```
steep check
```

The empty message means no error in the static type checker. To reproduce a static type error we can call the initializer with a string

```rb
# book.rb
Book.new("100")
```

the `steep check` will throw the following error

```
book.rb:11:22: ArgumentTypeMismatch: receiver=singleton(::Book), expected=::Integer, actual=::String ("100")
```

with this example, we can prove that we can validate our ruby programs using rbs type definitions.